# Python27 to upload a file to google drive does not work when run as a windows scheduled task. Why?

Tags: python-2.7, google-api-python-client

I had a similar issue when a Python script called from a scheduled task on a windows server tried to access a network shared drive. It would run from the IDLE on the server but not from the task. I switched to using a local drive it worked fine. This script works if run from console or IDLE on the server and partially executes when run as a scheduled task. It pulls data from a MSSQL database and creates a local csv. That works called from the task but the part to upload the file to a Google Drive does not. I have, as I did, before try other methods of calling outside of the scheduled task ex Powershell, bat file... but same results. I am using google-api-python-client (1.6.2) and can't find anything. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer. In the optional field of the Windows Scheduled Task Action dialog, "Start in" I added the path to the Python Scripts folder and the script now runs perfect.